# Number theory: efficient modular exponentiation

Tags: modular-arithmetic

If:

\begin{align}
k &= a\cdot b\cdot c\\ 
k_m &= k \bmod m\\
a_m &= a \bmod m\\
b_m &= b \bmod m\\
c_m &= c \bmod m\\
\end{align}

Then is $B^{k_m} \bmod N$ always equivalent to:

$$\left(\left(B^{a_m} \bmod N\right)^{b_m} \bmod N\right) ^ {c_m} \bmod N$$

If not, what is a counter example?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about general mathematics.

Answer (score 4):

> If not, what is a counter example?

Counterexample:

$a = 2, b = 2, c = 2, m = 3, N = 5, B = 2$

In this case, $k = 8$ and $k_m = 2$.

We have $B^{k_m} \bmod N = 4$, but $(((B^{a_m} \bmod N)^{b_m} \bmod N)^{c_m} \bmod N = 1$

On the other hand, if $N$ is prime, and $m = N-1$, then it is always true.

Answer (score 3):

By Euler's theorem, this is true for $m:= \phi(N)$, with $\phi$ being [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) (In the special case that $N$ is prime, you have $\phi(N)=N-1$, if $N$ is the product of two different primes $p$ and $q$, you have $\phi(N)=(p-1)(q-1)$), if $B_k$ and $N$ are coprime. In general, when calculating modulo $N$, you can calculate the exponent modulo $\phi(N)$, so you have

$k_m\equiv k=a\cdot b\cdot c\equiv a_m\cdot b_m\cdot c_m \mod \phi(N)$

and thus

$B^k_m\equiv B_m^{a_m\cdot b_m\cdot c_m} = (((B_m^{a_m})^{b_m})^{{c_m}})\mod N$.

If $m$ is an arbitrary number (or $B_k$ and $N$ have a common divisor other than $1$), the identity is false in general as poncho remarked.

Comment: Counterexample to your general relation: $a = 3, b = 3, c = 1, N = 16, B = 2$ :-)  Weird things can happen if you're not actually in $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$

Comment: Thanks, I completely forgot about requiring coprimality. I edited my answer. @poncho